# Athena - Union tables with incompatible data types

Tags: hiveql, amazon-athena, presto

We have two tables with a column differing in its data type. A column in first table is of type `int`, while the same column on second table is of type `float`/`real`. if it was a naked column I could have `CAST`'ed to a common type, the problem here is, these columns are deep inside a `struct`.

Error i'm getting is,

> SYNTAX_ERROR: line 23:1: column 4 in row(priceconfiguration row(maximumvalue integer, minimumvalue integer, type varchar, value integer)) query has incompatible types: Union, row(priceconfiguration row(maximumvalue integer, minimumvalue integer, type varchar, value real))

The query (simplified) is,

```
 WITH t1 AS (
   SELECT
     "so"."createdon"
   , "so"."modifiedon"
   , "so"."deletedon"
   , "so"."createdby"
   , "so"."priceconfiguration"
   , "so"."year"
   , "so"."month"
   , "so"."day"
   FROM
     my_db.raw_price so
   UNION ALL    
    SELECT
     "ao"."createdon"
   , "ao"."modifiedon"
   , "ao"."deletedon"
   , "ao"."createdby"
   , "ao"."priceconfiguration"
   , "ao"."year"
   , "ao"."month"
   , "ao"."day"
   FROM
     my_db.src_price ao
) 
SELECT t1.* FROM t1 ORDER BY "modifiedon" DESC
```

In fact, the real table is more complex than this and the column `priceconfiguration` is nested deep inside the tables. So `CAST`ing the column under question is directly not possible, unless all the `struct`s are un-nested to `CAST` the offending column.

Is there a way to `UNION` these two tables without `unnest`ing and `cast`ing?

Comment: Cast the entire `struct` column to a `string`. If you need to get into the struct again, you can cast it back, setting the troublesome `value` field as a `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade the Athena Engine Version to v2.

V2 Engine has more support for schema evolution. As per the AWS doc,

> Schema evolution support has been added for data in Parquet format.
>
> Added support for reading array, map, or row type columns from
> partitions where the partition schema is different from the table
> schema. This can occur when the table schema was updated after the
> partition was created. The changed column types must be compatible.
> For row types, trailing fields may be added or dropped, but the
> corresponding fields (by ordinal) must have the same name.

Ref:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/engine-versions-reference.html